# Whether my process is hung or running

Tags: linux, process, ps, gpu

I am running a heavy process on a Linux Machine with GPU. `nvidia-smi` shows 15GB/16GB used up. CPU utilization is around 70% and MEM around 98.5% but the `tqdm` progress bar of my process is not being updated for a while. How can I know whether it is actually running or is hung?

Comment: And in addition to the suggestions in the answer, check the swap by typing "swapon". It's possible you're thrashing.

Comment: ```swapon``` doesn't return anything. ```vmstat``` shows ```si``` and ```so``` to be ```0```.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- `strace -fF -p PID` it
- check whether its RAM or CPU use fluctuates
- check its log files via `tail -f`
- check whether its status in `ps ax` is running (R*), Sleeping (S*) or zombie (Z)

Comment: Unfortunately, my previous process got killed, so can't check its status. I am running the process again with smaller batch-size. It shows ```Rl+``` with CPU ```100``` and MEM ```63.8```. Not sure if 100% CPU utilization is a problem. MEM, VSZ, RSS are still increasing.

Comment: Would it be ```ps aux``` in the 4th point?